# Name of a particular kind of identity block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dynamical-systems, matrix-decomposition

Do matrices that have block structure made of identity matrices with negative identity matrices along the main diagonal have a name? More specifically, do matrices such as:

$$ {{A}_{n}}=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   -{{I}_{n}} & {{I}_{n}}  \\
   {{I}_{n}} & -{{I}_{n}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right] $$

have a particular name? Here $n$ is a nonzero positive integer and $I_n$ is an identity matrix of dimension $n$.

More generally do matrices that are "quasi-similar" to such these matrices have a name? $A_n$'s have $n$ zero eigenvalues and the remaining $n$ just equal to $-2$. Matrices *actually* similar to $A_n$ then should have the same eigenvalues. If we flip the signs of the blocks on each row, the non-zero but same-valued eigenvalues change signs.

By my "quasi-similar" I mean the same eigenvalue structure: $n$ zero eigenvalues and $n$ nonzero eigenvalues (a. possibly same, [but all negative or all positive] and b. possibly different [$n-1$ repeats of the non-zero ones are allowed as along as all $n$ have the same sign]).

I suspect this is related to symplectic matrices, but I am not familiar with the theory. The background of the question is that it arises from center-manifold theory and in particular systems that have *only* stable modes and a slow manifold.

References to related topics/matrices are also welcome in the comments.

—

**EDIT:** Maybe I should clarify that I am not looking for a "name"/*name*. In particular; if there is no name, then the accepted answer should be "There is no name for such kind of matrices". But that doesn't help me or future investigators: Instead I would rather prefer (if in fact there is no name) an answer that elucidates relationships with other groups/matrices/structures that *do* have a name.

Comment: For $n = 1$, this is (up to a scalar factor) the [Hadamard gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Hadamard_(H)_gate). But the notion of a Hadamard matrix is more general.